# Parsing expressions based on reflection

Tags: php, parsing, reflection, compiler-construction

I need to execute functions to calculate expressions, simimlar to Excel but in PHP (OOP). (This question is probably a peanut for anyone with language parser knowledge.)

The core engine analyzes the functions and their requirements (reflection), and should run appropriate functions, and in optimal sequence in order to:

- Resolve unknown values
- On set new value, update any dependent values

**Scenario**

```
a = b * c
b = c + d
c = 5
d = 8
e = f * 2
f = b + 3 + a
```

**Get any calculated value**

- Resolving **a** requires resolving **b**.
- Resolving **e** requires resolving **f** (which in turn requires resolving **a** and **b**).

**Set known value**

If **c** is changed, functions should run to recalculate values.

- [a = b * c] should be held back since it would be based on trashed b value.
- [b = c + d] should run since there are no unknown dependencies.
- Any functions dependent to **b** should now also run so [a = b * c] could run.
- By updating **a** function  [f = b + 3 + a] should now run.
- Likewise, function **e** should now run.

**Question**

My question is about **the algorithm** for resolving and setting values.

- Allthough it appears to be a subject for recursive parsing, is it more wise iterate over an array of functions and put any unresolved requirements to the end?

For example: [Update C] should not run in source order [a=..], [b=..], but [b=], [a=].

- Should the SET logic be used already when resolving values, and if so, wouldn't that make the parsing of looking up values above redundant? Upon class initialisation, constants would be set and dependent functions would run.

Recursive exection example:

```
[Update C] =>
  [Update B] =>
    [Update A] =>
      [Update F] =>
        [Update E] =>
```

Once again, should this execution order be called recursivly or similar to above, by iterating over a flat array.

Thankful for any references or principles in the matter.

Comment: What programming language allows `a = b * c`
`b = c + d`
`c = 5` in that order?

Comment: it's not ordinary variables but type-data. the formulas exists in class methods. think excel [a1]: =b1+3, [b1]: 5

Comment: In Excel if the cell is blank it is treated as `0`.  I might parse the data assigning undefined vars `0` and then parse again.  Parsing twice might be easier.

Answer (score 2):

This is not OO code, but more a proof of concept (and I was bored).

The code is basically split into 2 halves.  First is the code which effectively tokenizes the strings and then creates a dependency list for each variable.  So a depends on b and c etc.

The second part is a brute force system which goes through each dependency list and checks if all of the dependencies are solvable, each time it can solve it (all the dependant fields are known), it adds a sequence to the variable list to say what order they can be run in.  It keeps on doing this until all are solvable or it makes no more progress (which may be something like a=b and b=a).

I've added comments in the code, may be of help...

```
$equations = [
    "a = b * c",
    "b = c + d",
    "c = 5",
    "d = 8",
    "e = f * 2",
    "f = b + 3 + a",
];

$variables = [];
$toBeSolved = [];
$symbols = ["=", "*", "+", "-", "/"];
$evalSeq = 0;
// Extract dependencies and known values
foreach ( $equations as $equation ) {
    $parts = explode ( " ", $equation);
    $equationVars = [];
    $leftVar = array_shift($parts);
    $variables[$leftVar] = null;
    foreach ( $parts as $part ) {
        if ( !in_array ($part, $symbols) && !is_numeric($part) )  {
            $variables[$part] = null;
            $equationVars[] = $part;
        }
    }
    // If there are dependant values, add to list of things to be solved
    if ( count($equationVars) > 0 ) {
        $toBeSolved[$leftVar] = $equationVars;
    }
    // No dependants, so just log sequence as solved
    else    {
        $variables[$leftVar] = $evalSeq++;
    }
}

// Find equations solvable, carry on whilst unknowns left
while ( count($toBeSolved) > 0 ){
    $progress = 0;
    foreach ( $toBeSolved as $var => $dep )   {
        $known = true;
        foreach ( $dep as $variable )   {
            // Flag an unknown variable, so can't solve this yet
            if ( $variables[$variable] === null )    {
                $known = false;
                break;
            }
        }
        // If all values are known, then can be evaluated, so log sequence and remove
        if ( $known )   {
            $variables[$var] = $evalSeq++;
            unset ($toBeSolved[$var]);
            $progress++;
        }
    }
    // If no progress has been made, then can't reduce further.
    if ( $progress == 0 ){
        break;
    }
}
print_r($variables);
// If $toBeSolved is not empty, then can't solve
print_r($toBeSolved);
```

The end result is something like...

```
Array
(
    [a] => 3
    [b] => 2
    [c] => 0
    [d] => 1
    [e] => 5
    [f] => 4
)
```

showing that the order to evaluate in is c,d,b,a,f,e.

It may be possible that instead of storing the sequence, you could store the values instead, so as each pass is made you can calculate the result of the equation and store that alongside the variable name.

Comment: Looks very interesting! Boredom at its best. ;) Big thanks for commenting the code.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the question consists of two separate ones. The goal is still not too clear, but I'll try to answer.

The first one is that your syntax allows "forward references". This code is an exact example of it:

```
e = f * 2
f = b + 3 + a
```

Variable declaration `e` references an entity declared later (`f`) in its body, so you definitely can't resolve it during one parsing pass over your source code. The closest behavior could be found in the JavaScript language, where the [hoisting](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Hoisting) works in a similar manner. As far as I know, to implement that a runtime traverses this code twice. At first, it collects all the declarations existing in the current scope. And during the second pass, it can find a corresponding declaration node, referenced by an executed function. It's an oversimplification of course, but I hope that a general idea is clear.

The second problem is that the execution order is not defined. Or it could be said that it is defined implicitly by the dependencies of declared functions. So if you want to calculate the execution order based on those dependencies, you can implement a canonical [topological sorting](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Topological_sorting) algorithm. You should be careful with cycle references because this algorithm won't be able to find a correct sequence in that case.

Also if the grammar of your language is more complicated than simple arithmetic expressions (even in that case you should think about operator precedence and associativity, for example), it's better to find some library for symbolic computation, maybe it will simplify your task significantly.